# How to start master/detail in Activity

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments, master-detail

When I will start my master/detail activity(FolderListActivity) from another activity

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext, FolderListActivity.class))) 
or
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext, FolderDetailActivity.class)))
```

it shows only one side in full screen. It works in separately project.
How to properly show  my master/detail. As shown below:
[image: Master-Detail]

**Details**

**AndroidManifies.xml**:

```
<activity
    ...
</activity>
<activity
    ...
</activity>
  <activity
    android:name="com.mypck.FolderListActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="com.mypck.FolderDetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_folder_detail"
    android:parentActivityName=".FolderListActivity" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".FolderListActivity" />
</activity>
```

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18120852/unable-to-startactivity-master-detail-from-another-activity), but there is no useful answer for me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I did fix it. There was my error, when I moved to my current project I forgot values-large. It has a specific item for large devices.

**refs.xml**

```
<resources>

    <item name="activity_folder_list" type="layout">@layout/activity_folder_twopane</item>

</resources>
```

Regards. B&B